# Windows server standard, processes not able to utilize all physical CPU

Tags: windows, performance, licensing

Please find the attached picture.
I have windows server 2019. with SQL server web edition and IIS.
the CPU always shows (on all 4 servers of same specification) that its utilizing only 48 cores (out of 96 cores (logical))

As you can see 48 cores are always at 100% utilization and the rest are almost sleeping. What could be a possible reason as the server provider gave us fully licensed windows. we do not have any limitation set manually.

[image: server picture]

Answer (score 2):

*As vidarlo has already mentioned, your CPUs have total 48 cores/96 logical processors (due to hyperthreading).*

[According to Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2019), SQL Server Web Edition supports up to 16 cores:

## Scale limits

| Feature | Enterprise | Standard | Web | Express with Advanced Services | Express |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Maximum compute capacity used by a single instance - SQL Server Database Engine | Operating system maximum | Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores | Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores | Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores | Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores |
| Maximum compute capacity used by a single instance - Analysis Services or Reporting Services | Operating system maximum | Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 24 cores | Limited to lesser of 4 sockets or 16 cores | Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores | Limited to lesser of 1 socket or 4 cores |
| Maximum memory for buffer pool per instance of SQL Server Database Engine | Operating System Maximum | 128 GB | 64 GB | 1410 MB | 1410 MB |
| Maximum memory for Columnstore segment cache per instance of SQL Server Database Engine | Unlimited memory | 32 GB | 16 GB | 352 MB | 352 MB |
| Maximum memory-optimized data size per database in SQL Server Database Engine | Unlimited memory | 32 GB | 16 GB | 352 MB | 352 MB |
| Maximum memory utilized per instance of Analysis Services | Operating System Maximum | 16 GB | 64 GB | N/A | N/A |
| Maximum memory utilized per instance of Reporting Services | Operating System Maximum | 64 GB | 64 GB | 4 GB | N/A |
| Maximum relational database size | 524 PB | 524 PB | 524 PB | 10 GB | 10 GB |

So you need an Enterprise Edition, in order to utilize all 48 cores.

Comment: So what's the answer if the logical count is 96 and SQL Server is enterprise edition yet it only is using 48 of them? Yes, that is the situation I am seeing on a system.

Answer (score 1):

Xeon Gold 5318Y has [24 cores](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/215271/intel-xeon-gold-5318y-processor-36m-cache-2-10-ghz/specifications.html). You have two sockets, for a total of 48 physical cores.

It however supports [hyper-threading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading), which means that *some* tasks can run concurrently on a single core. So the likely answer is that due to the workload you have, you'll never see full load on all logical cores - only on the physical ones.

Comment: you mean to say that CPU is 100% being used but its showing wrong usage? that all cores are not being used?

but i see the same type of load (Evenly distributed on all cores in task manager, on 20 core CPU). 
that server also has 2 sockets, each has 10 cores, and it shows even load on all cores(logical).

Comment: You have 48 cores, not 96. All cores are used. Hyperthreading doesn't work for all workloads.

Comment: you did not read what specificailly i asked. IF it is 48 cores not 96, then why other server with 20 cores is able to utilize 100% of all cores?

Comment: I think it's probably a combination with the process limit mentioned in the other answer.